# How to integarte .cer file(server certificate) with xmlHttpRequest to call a web service in Hybrid Application using ionic/cordova/angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to integrate .cer file(Server certificate) with xmlHttpRequest to call a web service in hybrid application. Any one have any idea how to implement it in ionic/cordova/angular. Thanks